# Add the same link multiple times in the pivot table in October CMS

Tags: many-to-many, octobercms

I have two tables, having many-to-many relationship between them (user, shop) and a pivot table (visit) that links them together:

```
table user {
    id,
    name
}

table shop {
    id,
    name
}

table visit {
    id,
    user_id,
    shop_id,
    date
}
```

On the user's backend page, I'd like to be able to add multiple visits to the same shop. I use relation config, and a table is displayed, having an "Add" button on top. The problem is that when I press the "Add" button, the list of shops appears, but that won't contain any shop, which has already been added to the pivot table for the current user.

How could I resolve this in the simplest way?

Comment: You should add `count` field in the `pivot`(visit) table instead, and increase the count as per your like. as per my opinion that would be best. and on the front end based on the count, you can loop or show raw count and apply logic as per your need. (any how that data will be repeated so)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not enough to only know the count of those visits. I also need to have other info about them, e.g. the date.

Comment: oh yes in that case you need multiple entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the RelationController it's being prevented to add multiple times the same link in the pivot table (https://github.com/wintercms/winter/blob/develop/modules/backend/behaviors/RelationController.php, lines 936-945). One solution would be to extend the RelationController, to override that method and to delete these lines.

I used a different approach, where I transformed the pivot table to a regular table. Now there are one-to-many relationships between visit-user and visit-shop. This way it's possible to add the same relationship multiple times.